# WCF Rest Service Error Acess Denied

Tags: wcf, rest

Created a WCF Rest Service. It works fine with URL like `localhost` but when access it with `192.168.1.41` (ipaddress) it throws error "`Access Denied`".

Tried all the suggestions like Permissions, Enabled Tracing (but nothing logged).

Any Suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="coTrainServBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="CoTrain.CoTrainService" behaviorConfiguration="coTrainServBehavior">
        <endpoint address="rh" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="CoTrain.ICoTrainService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
           logEntireMessage="true"
           logMalformedMessages="true"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
           maxMessagesToLog="3000"
           maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
    </diagnostics>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
               switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing, Error, Warning, Critical" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="D:\CoTrainPublished\messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CoTrainEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.CoTrainModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.CoTrainModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.CoTrainModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.1.11;initial catalog=CoTrain;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=TestServer@123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Thanks
Anand

Comment: Paste your Web.Config file.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a personal firewall/HIPS (host intrusion protection system)? I encountered a problem exactly like this before, where a localhost reference to my website goes through without errors, but accessing it over my IP address or even the local loopback 127.0.0.1 made my page unreachable. I found out that the HIPS installed blocked HTTP requests going into my machine, which effectively cuts you off to regular web page access.